# SelectedValue binding of a nested DataGrid doesn't work while ItemsSource does

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, user-controls

I have a `DataGrid` inside of a `UserControl` which in turn lies inside of another `UserControl`. This is due to other needs of the project and I can't change this nested architecture. I'm binding a list of `Person` class to this `DataGrid`. This is a dumbed-down version without using a `VM`, but in my real project I am using a `VM`.

### My `UserControl` with the `DataGrid`:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="MyDg"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:UCDataGrid}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        MouseDoubleClick="MyDg_MouseDoubleClick"
        SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:UCDataGrid}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</Grid>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
public partial class UCDataGrid : UserControl
{
    public event RoutedEventHandler RoutedDataGridDoubleClick;

    public UCDataGrid()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(object), typeof(UCDataGrid), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public object ItemsSource
    {
        get { return GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedValue", typeof(object), typeof(UCDataGrid), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public object SelectedValue
    {
        get { return GetValue(SelectedValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedValueProperty, value); }
    }

    private void MyDg_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        RoutedDataGridDoubleClick?.Invoke(this, new RoutedEventArgs());
    }
}
```

### 2nd `UserControl` that contains the above control:

```
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding MyDataGrid, ElementName=ucDisplay}"/>
</Grid>
```

`ucDisplay` is simply the `Name` property value of this `UserControl`.

**Code Behind:**

Nothing fancy here.

```
public partial class UCDisplay : UserControl
{
    public UCDisplay()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyDataGridProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyDataGrid", typeof(object), typeof(UCDisplay), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public object MyDataGrid
    {
        get { return GetValue(MyDataGridProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyDataGridProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

### Main Window

In my Main Window, I bind my `People` list as well as `SelectedPerson` instance, like so:

```
<Grid>
    <local:UCDisplay>
        <local:UCDisplay.MyDataGrid>
            <local:UCDataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding People}"
                              SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedPerson, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                              RoutedDataGridDoubleClick="UCDataGrid_RoutedDataGridDoubleClick"/>
        </local:UCDisplay.MyDataGrid>
    </local:UCDisplay>
</Grid>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    private List<Person> people;
    public List<Person> People
    {
        get => people;
        set => SetField(ref people, value);
    }

    private Person selectedPerson;
    public Person SelectedPerson
    {
        get => selectedPerson;
        set => SetField(ref selectedPerson, value);
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        People = GetPeople();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void UCDataGrid_RoutedDataGridDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private List<Person> GetPeople()
    {
        return new List<Person>
        {
            new Person() { Name = "A" },
            new Person() { Name = "B" },
            new Person() { Name = "C" }
        };
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Again, in reality I'm using a `VM`, this is only to keep things simple.

Now when I run this I can display my list content just fine. But when I double-click an item in my `DataGrid`, in the corresponding in my Main Window code behind, the `SelectedPerson` remains `null`, although its binding is identical to the `People` list. I confirm this by using a break point in the main code behind:

[image]

But if I debug and see the value in the code behind of my innermost `UserControl`, you see that the `SelectedValue` there has the correct selected items value.

[image]

So what am I doing wrong here? Why can't I seem to bind the `SelectedValue` although I do it exactly the same as my `ItemsSource` binding, but the latter works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelectedValue` is supposed to be used in conjunction with `SelectedValuePath`. You should use `SelectedItem` instead.

Besides that, you are missing a `TwoWay` Binding. Either explicitly declare the `SelectedItem` Binding TwoWay

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyDg"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource,
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem,
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

or register the property to bind TwoWay by default:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(SelectedItem), typeof(object), typeof(UCDataGrid),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

public object SelectedItem
{
    get { return GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
}
```

Also note that setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is pointless in all your Bindings.

Comment: thanks! I somehow thought that TwoWay binding was the default and if unspecified that's what the binding would be. Guess I was wrong.